# Calling a function defined within knockout js ViewModel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a html 5 view and want to perform Drag and Drop. In my html I have a knockout foreach as given below. The **`li`** element is being dragged on.

```
<ul class="games-list" data-bind="foreach: games">
    <li data-bind="text: name, attr: { 'data-dragdrop': id }" 
        ondragstart='setTransferProperties(event)' 
        draggable="true">
    </li>
</ul>
```

and here is the javascript with `knockout ViewModel`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var AppScope = function () {

        ...//plain js object here

        //knockout js View Model
        function PlayersViewModel() {
            var self = this

            self.games = ko.observableArray([
                                            new Game({ id: 0, name: "Cricket" }),
                                            new Game({ id: 1, name: "Football" }),
                                            new Game({ id: 2, name: "Hockey" })
                                            ]);
            ...
            //Drag and Drop
            self.setTransferProperties = function (event) { //Not invoked
                event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.getAttribute('data-dragdrop'));
            };
        }
    }
```

With the above the **setTransferProperties(event)** is looked for in AppScope, instead of inside the `knockout ViewModel`, and hence not found.

What would be the way to invoke the **setTransferProperties(event)** defined in the knockout ViewModel when performing the Drag.

Comment: Can we know where is the games observable array in your ViewMode?

Comment: @G_S Its inside the PlayersViewModel(). I have edited the question and shown its definition in the code.

Comment: I guess $root.setTransferProperties(...) would work for you if you are applying binding on playersViewModel

Comment: take a look [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/02/revisiting-dragging-dropping-and.html) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wilsonhut/2nj9J/)

Comment: @raheel, Actually, I missed out basic part that ondragstart, ondrop, are just events and so, I am better able to handle them using the Kockout Event Binding (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html). A great advantage of using Event Binding is that the current $data (context) is also passed to the event handler (as the first parameter), along with the event (as second parameter). Thanks all

Comment: try creating a fiddle so that we can check it

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following

```
<ul class="games-list" data-bind="foreach: games">
    <li data-bind="text: name, attr: { 
                        'data-dragdrop': id ,
                        'ondragstart':$parent.setTransferProperties
        }" 
        draggable="true">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does $parent refer to games? and since you are saying $parent.setTransfer..... wouldnt it search for a method in games object? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: $parent will refer to `PlayersViewModel` and `setTransferProperties` will be accessiable. And in the loop `setTransferProperties` will take current object as a parameter. `setTransferProperties` and `games` are on the same level so there should be no problem

Comment: @G_S and raheel, I tried your solutions, but I don't know from where I am getting a strange error, which says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( ". I have no clue why such error pops up. If I use the browser console to see on which line it occurs, then it points to the ending </script> tag of the javascript.